# database structure for multiple single column indices

Tags: database, indexing

Assume I have a table Business and I create an index on column 'country'
As per my understanding, the DB will break up table into (sort of) chunks where one or more chunk is dedicated on a per country basis. Like so:

chunk1 = records for country US

chunk2 = records for country US

chunk3 = records for country IN

chunk4 = records for country NZ....

If I now create a **separate** index on column 'businessType' then how will the database structure look like?

Will the DB create 2 separate copies of the data, one indexed by country and one indexed by businessType?

OR

Will the DB create chunks so that for each chunk contains data on a per-country and per-businessType basis? Like so

chunk1 = records for country = US & businessType = IT

chunk2 = records for country = US & businessType = Finance

chunk3 = records for country = US & businessType = Finance

chunk4 = records for country = US & businessType = Finance

chunk5 = records for country = IN & businessType = IT

chunk6 = records for country = IN & businessType = IT

chunk7 = records for country = IN & businessType = Agriculture ......

Comment: As @Thilo says, also some RDBMS such as MySQL/InnoDB actually store the table itself as a b-tree and have all indices refer to a primary index.

Comment: @reve_etrange: Yes, Oracle has that, too, they call it Index-Organized-Table. But that requires that you have a primary key. In effect, you store the whole record within the primary key index (and the table as such does not exist physically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume I have a table Business and I create an index on column 'country' As per my understanding, the DB will break up table into (sort of) chunks where one or more chunk is dedicated on a per country basis

Nope. Your understanding is wrong.

The table will not be broken up, it will have the records in a big chunk, at first in roughly insertion order.

The *index* is what is organized in chunks, if you will (even though it is usually more like a tree structure).

The index stores the indexed column value and a pointer the location of the record in the table itself.

> If I now create a separate index on column 'businessType' then how will the database structure look like?

The table storage structure will not change at all. You will just have some additional indexes.

> Will the DB create 2 separate copies of the data, one indexed by country and one indexed by businessType?

If you create a separate index on the column 'businessType', then you will have a tree structure organized by only 'businessType'. This is completely independent of the other index you created earlier.

> Will the DB create chunks so that for each chunk contains data on a per-country and per-businessType basis?

If you create a *composite* index on (country, businessType), then you will indeed get an index that is "chunked" by both columns: The first level of the tree will dispatch on country, the second one (for a given country) on businessType.

Comment: _The table storage structure will not change at all._ I am not sure I understand. When we create an index, don't the records get rearranged to properly serve the index

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. My question is basically about the difference between a clustered and non-clustered index